# CSS working only on one page but not on the other

Tags: html, css, browser

I'm making a website for myself (for my jewelry business :) ), for the first time. I can't figure out why css is applyed on one page but not on the other, code for getting css is in both html files the same `<link rel="stylesheet" href="shizoid.css">` and they are sharing the same css file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4uPL.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6DuQ.jpg

You can see on the photos above, for example, in html is tag: 
    `<h1>Extravagant, Unique, Handmade Jewelry and Crafts</h1>`
and in css the moderation for it is:

```
h1 {
        background-color: #a018ba;
        border-radius: 15px;
        font-family: Garamond;
        font-size: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
```

On one page this is working, and on the other isn't. It is like thas from yesterday, it was ok before. I tried to view it both in Firefox and Chrome and on two different computers. I'm looking but I can't see, please help. :)

Comment: Can you post the paths of your pages and the link tag you are using in each? My guess is that you don't have an absolute path or start with a slash / in your css path, and that's fine for top-level pages but anything within a subfolder wouldn't find the css. Again, just a guess until you post a little example code.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but actually something weird happened- I was experimenting with two css files with slightly different names, and Sublime confused them, even though they weren't in the same folder; Notepad solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that it is generally better to apply styles such as borders and backgrounds to a div and then put the h1 into it. For example, your CSS would look something like:

```
#title-box { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: #a018ba; border-radius: 15px;  text-align: center; }
h1 { font-family: Garamond; font-size: 40px; }
```

And your HTML would look like:

```
<div id="title-box"><h1>Extravagant, Unique, Handmade Jewelry and Crafts</h1></div>
```

From the photos you posted, I would think that perhaps there is some error elsewhere in your code, such as a  without a corresponding  that is causing the CSS to not be applied.

Comment: Thank you for your god advice, but something weird happened- I was experimenting with two css files with slightly different names, and Sublime confused them, even though they weren't in the same folder; Notepad solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without further information on your website it is hard to determine the actual problem, my first guess is that your second webpage is located in a folder and you haven't updated your CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../shizoid.css">
```

If your webpage is on a different folder you can use this href to access the previous directory.

Comment: Thank you for an effort, that sounds logical, but it was something more weird - I was experimenting with two css files with slightly different names, and Sublime confused them, even though they weren't in the same folder; Notepad solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong in your idea .It is not css related problem.
    Your images are difference. You can see just drag each image and move each image in the browser.You can see that each image has difference.Your whole site is just an image. There is no such kind of tags like you mention `<h1>Extravagant, Unique, Handmade Jewelry and Crafts</h1>` in your whole html code .Just I posted an image check it either save it in your local drive or drag and drop each image in the new tab browser.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope the answer.

Comment: Thank you, but there was a slight misunderstanding - I forgot to mention that my website didn't lounch on the internet yet, that is way I've sent pictures.

Comment: Live your site I would like to inspect !

Answer (score 0):

I would place the CSS (if it is site wide), in a folder called CSS in your root folder. Then you can simply call the script like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/shizoid.css">
```

From any page...

The initial '/' takes you back to the root of your site.